# Can I dump the inventory to a remote machine in a task?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I have an Ansible role where I need to create an inventory file on the remote machine. I want to use the current inventory file, but with one single group removed.

For example, if I have the following inventory:

```
[operator]
host1.example.com

[control]
host2.example.com
host3.example.com

[compute]
host4.example.com some_var=value
host5.example.com

# some comment
[foo:children]
control
compute

[bar:vars]
var1=value
#var2=value
```

Then I need something that copies this:

```
- hosts: operator
  tasks:
    - name: Create inventory
      ...
```

With the following result on `host1.example.com`:

```
[control]
host2.example.com
host3.example.com

[compute]
host4.example.com some_var=value
host5.example.com

# some comment
[foo:children]
control
compute

[bar:vars]
var1=value
#var2=value
```

Comment: What is the reason behind this need, by the way? What problem does removing a single group solve?

Comment: I am preparing to run a third party package which actually also uses Ansible under the hood, so they expect an Inventory file. I figured I could avoid making two inventory files and just reuse my "main" one, but without my operator in it.

Comment: And the reason I need to remove operator is because this third party runs against `all`.

Comment: So don't run against `all`. Exclude the `operator` group. Problem solved. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_patterns.html

Comment: It's from a third party so I cannot control it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Split the current inventory file into two:

   - one containing the `operator` group only,
   - one containing the rest.
2. Copy only the latter to the target system.

---

<sup>You know that you can [point to a directory containing multiple files](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html) as your inventory, right?</sup>